# Different shading on same objects

Tags: shaders

These two objects have same settings (same material, same object settings, both are cut out + extruded pices of a sphere), but the smaller one has wery different shading. How to fix?

[image]

[image: all the normals are OK]

all the normals are OK

Comment: did you use smooth shading? Maybe you should move the edge loops?

Comment: Yes, it's smooth shading. What edge loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the loopcuts (one by one) and use the edge slide <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> --> edge slide. and move them to the sides. Or you can move them by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> two times so it will slide along the edges.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! :D I'll probably use "loop Cut and Slide" because without the edges the middle looks too blocky.